# Como recoger los datos de JSON en JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

Tengo esta vista de los datos en un JSON en JQuery

[image: vista de JSON en un array JQuery]

y quiero hacer algo similar a lo que se hace con los datos de laravel para coger el dato y contrastarlo con otros, he hecho algo como esto...

```
console.log(resenia[0]{cmt_libro_id});

        for (j = 0; j <length($resenia); j++) {

            if (resenia[j]{cmt_libro_id}==id)
            {
                cmt_no[j] = resenia[j]{cmt_no};
                cmt_titulo[j] =resenia[j]{cmt_no};

            }
        }
```

Comment: Ese código da error (de compilación), pero tampoco tengo claro qué es lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Simplemente quiero extraer el dato "cmt_libro_id" del json resenia para valorar si es igual que el id en el if. Para pasar el json a JQuery hice lo siguiente:  var resenia={!!$resenia->toJson(JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)!!};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La sintaxis en Javascript para obtener un atributo es como la del siguente ejemplo:

```js
let obj= [
  { attr1 : 1},
  { attr1 : 2},
  { attr1 : 3},
  { attr1 : 4}
];

console.log(obj[0].attr1); //opcion 1
console.log(obj[2]['attr1']); //opcion 2
```

Comment: Gracias por la info, ahora podré seguir en el proyecto.